# Auto Login in Wordpress Admin using Snoopy class fails

Tags: php, wordpress, session-cookies, autologin, snoopy

I want to Auto login to my wordpress admin to perform some Actions so i used [snoopy php class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) for this. My sample code is here

```
<?php
include 'Snoopy.class.php';
$snoopy = new Snoopy;
 $submit_url = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php";   
 $submit_vars["log"] = "admin"; //username
 $submit_vars["pwd"] = "admin";  //password
 $submit_vars["rememberme"] = "forever"; 
 $submit_vars["redirect_to"] = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/";
 $submit_vars["testcookie"] = "1";
 $submit_vars["wp_submit"] = "submit"; 
 $snoopy->submit($submit_url,$submit_vars); 
print $snoopy->results; 
 ?>
```

But I'm getting:

```
ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.
```

Though, I can login manually but this isn't working and cookies are also enabled in my browser.

What i'm doing wrong? and how can i make this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Print the header:

```
print_r ($snoopy->headers);
```

Output:

```
... [5] => Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; ...
```

But print the cookies

```
print_r ($snoopy->cookies);
```

delivers

```
... [wordpress_test_cookie] => WP Cookie check ...
```

Solution: Set

```
$snoopy->cookies['wordpress_test_cookie']="WP+Cookie+check";
```

manually before submit, because Snoopy clear the cookie content in plaintext and set the "+" in whitespace.